# Injecting locking policy into a class

Tags: c#, concurrency

I have a class that does some operations on data, and I want to have different locking schemes (no-lock, simple-lock, and read reader-writer lock) in different situations.

Think this main class like a collection class. In one instance this collection gets populated by data from a file and on a single thread. In this case I don't to use any locking. Where as, in other scenarios, the collection data is populated by multiple Rx-streams (and potentially on multiple threads) and I want to have some locking mechanism in place.

So, I have decided I would abstract the actual locking into a different policy class, and would inject this locking policy class into the main class.

Below is the class diagram for my locking policy interfaces/classes:

[image]

The main class would invoke EnterRead/EnterWrite methods on policy to acquire lock, before doing any read/write operations on data. And, when the operation is done, the class releases the lock by disposing the locking token returned by EnterRead/EnterWrite methods.

My question is, am I right in thinking that I could abstract locking scheme out into separate classes or would I get myself into a pickle by going down this path?

**UPDATE**

Below is the implementation of a simple lock token class. This is a private class in `SimpleLockPolicy` and the policy creates a token by doing `new SimpleLockToken(_syncLock)` when a thread invokes EnterRead/EnterWrite methods.

```
class SimpleLockToken : IDisposable
{
    private readonly object _lock;

    public SyncLockToken(object syncLock)
    {
        _lock = syncLock;
        Monitor.Enter(_lock);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_lock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "different situations".  What particular problem are you trying to solve?  Normally wouldn't a locking token have to be _shared_ to be used between threads (ie, can't dispose it afterwards)?  It feels like attempting to do this will make you **think** you're running stuff safely, but at some point you're going to put `NoLockingPolicy` instead of `SimpleLockPolicy`, and then...

Comment: Yes, the locking object itself is shared across the threads. Policy class internally has a locking object and wraps it into a token class when a thread calls EnterRead/EnterWrite methods on policy. I have updated question with implementation for simple lock token class for more clarity.

Comment: Note: `Dispose` isn't guaranteed to be called by the framework, so things could be locked longer than you think.  Naming your release-lock method that is going to confuse people no end (that, and while you can safely call `Monitor.Enter(...)` multiple times, you need the same number of `Exit(...)` calls).  My question was less about the exact implementation of the policy classes, and why you think you need them, or what the code calling them is actually doing.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I edited question and added usage scenario in second paragraph. In the last couple of days, I started going down this path and I already started to feel the pain (e.g. leaking reader-writer lock specific methods into the common lock policy interface). I am going to do away with this policy approach and have the locking semantics baked into couple of specialized classes themselves derived from the Main class.

Comment: ...at the point where you'd know what your read/write situation is, you could use specialized collections instead of this locking policy.  In the second instance it sounds like you want ConcurrentQueue, or maybe to implement the reader/writer interface in System.Collections.Concurrent